# SharePoint Online Add-ins no longer work with new document library UX experience in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365-developer

We are a solution developer in SharePoint and publish our apps on the SharePoint store. With this new SharePoint library experience UX, the add-ins are no longer supported. You click on them and nothing happens. This seems to be the case with other add-ins as well that show in the ribbon. What's the store here.

- How can we do a quick fix to get those add-in buttons working again in the new experience this is essential and causing a lot of problems.

Our add-in is a provider hosted app.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for us to know how you've implemented your app, so we can't give you any specific advice.  If your app utilizes anything listed in this article, then you're out of luck for the time being.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-the-new-document-library-experience-and-classic-mode-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc

Comment: Thanks Eric, I don't think this is specific to our app because other add-ins we installed all behave the same way. The behavior is they show up as an icon in the top of the new library experience, but when you click on the icon 'nothing' happens at all. Try installing an app and trying it out. Our App is Tru Copy but you can try any other app from the store.